# filter datatables with same prefix but different suffix in numbers

Tags: filter, datatables

I am using dataTables for a class list of students. One of my tables looks like this

Student Name    ||  Class Name

Victoria Say    ||  Grade 1 
Phillip Hey     ||      Grade 1 
Stephen Chew    ||     Grade 3 
Marian Boot     ||      Grade 2 
Mary Brave      ||      Grade 3 
Betty Nancy     ||      Form 1 
Bright Hanson   ||      Form 3

If I type 'Grade 3' in the search box, 
 instead of returning, [Stephen Chew and Mary Brave], 
 the table
returns all the five members whose Class Name contains the word [Grade]. 
 How would I able to return
only the [Grade 3] students using the search box. 
 Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to disable the default search handler and attach your own. Then inside your search function you need to use [search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()) and set regex to `true` and smart search to `false` so that it only returns exact matches.

```js
$('.dataTables_filter input', dt.table().container())
    .off('.DT')
    .on('keyup.DT cut.DT paste.DT input.DT search.DT', function(e) {
        table.search(`^${this.value}$`, true, false).draw();
    }
```

Where `table` is a JQuery reference to your DataTable. E.g.

```js
const table = $('#tableId').DataTable();
```